# HM-10 Central mode starting a connection

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to issue a connection via HM-10 from arduino (rather than my phone).
However, I'm unable to start a connection from arduino using both AT+CON and AT+CONNL. When I try AT+CON I get `OK+CONNA` and when I use AT+CONNL I get `OK+CONNE`. Here's my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(8,9);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(50);
  bluetooth.begin(115200); //open BLE connection
  bluetooth.setTimeout(50); //set timeout
  bluetooth.write("AT+ROLE1");
  //bluetooth.write("AT+ROLE0");
  delay(50);
  bluetooth.write("AT+NOTI1");
  delay(50);
  bluetooth.write("AT+CONC40BCB403020");
  delay(50);
  //bluetooth.write("AT+CONNL");
}

void loop() {
    while (bluetooth.available() > 0) {
      String response = bluetooth.readString();
      Serial.println(response);
    }
}
```

The response that I get is:

```
OK+Set:1
OK+Set:1
OK+CONNA
```

Comment: Can you let us know what is the response to the commands `AT+CON` and `AT+CONN` after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

By now you've surely moved past this, but: I found that I had to try connecting multiple times in order to get a connection to complete.  Also, your timeout might need to be longer?